# Download OneNote via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to use the [Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/integrate_with_onenote) to download and save a OneNote notebook locally.

I am aware that OneNote is split in `Notebooks`, `Sections`, `Pages` etc. and that the `Page` has the `stream`able content. I am able to get all these parts successfully using the [OneNote API](https://dev.onenote.com/docs).

When I download my OneNote Notebook from my OneDrive *via the portal* it splits it up into multiple files as follows:

[image]

So:

- Every section is saved with the `.one` extension
- There is a `.onetoc2` extension (always named the *Open Notebook*) which I've assumed to mean "Table of Contents"
- I can successfully open the `.onetoc2` with my local OneNote 2016 installation and see all my sections and pages with their correct content.

Great. This seems reasonable so far. Here is where I'm stuck...

1. Each section has multiple pages. How are these multiple streams combined and saved into a single `.one` section?
2. How do I create the `.onetoc2` (table of contents) file? I cannot seem to find any documentation about this nor an API to help create these files.

There does seem to be a strong push from Microsoft to keep files Online and I get that. But my premise for going down this route is that we need to (programmably) get a hard local version to be backed up backup software which will be restorable back into both the cloud **and locally**. So at some point I need to create these local files.

Thanks in advance for any help.